# The layout could not be loaded

Tags: android-layout, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin, after installing i'm trying to make a Hello Android app, I made it! However, when I try to open Main.axml the app layout, I get this error:

*System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException: Aucune exportation correspondant à la contrainte 
ContractName VisualStudioWorkspace
RequiredTypeIdentity Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace n'a été trouvée.
à System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
à System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportsCore(Type type, Type metadataViewType, String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
à System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueCore[T](String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
à Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerInterface.GetCodeModelBridge() dans c:\data\lanes\3513\680125b0\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerInterface.cs:ligne 154
à Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.get_CodeModelBridge()
à Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.d__175.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
à Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.d__139.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
à Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidRenderSession.d__105.MoveNext()*

I have tried to delete cache in C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
but stil not working

Comment: This error happens on the Visual Studio designer?

Comment: Code of your layout then?

Comment: Thank you  apineda and Grace Feng for replaying me. the error is happen on Visual Studio Deseigner as apineda told me and specialy on Main.axml.
And this is the code of layout :


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
</LinearLayout>

Comment: hi all, i have resolve the issue, i have instal same update of xamarin and it works right now, but i have another issue about my emulator 
"resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8" i have tried to increase memory bit stil not working